# Burninate the [preview] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I believe the [preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preview) (900 Questions) tag is useless, because:

- It contains many unrelated questions.

  - Most of them are about previewing *something*, be it video files, documents, websites, streams of bytes,.. This tag is not really helpful forfinding or answering questions.
- No one can be an expert in previews.
- IMHO, It is a "meta tag"

Some examples of questions:

- [Responsive Site Blank Print Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396394/responsive-site-blank-print-preview) (retag to [print-preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/print-preview))
- [how to get byte array from camera preview in java android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394536/how-to-get-byte-array-from-camera-preview-in-java-android)
- [Can I format Yahoo Link Preview from a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372761/can-i-format-yahoo-link-preview-from-a-website)
- [Rotate video preview in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984866/rotate-video-preview-in-matlab)
- [365 API to run OneDrive on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368780/365-api-to-run-onedrive-on-linux)

IMO, Some of these should be retagged:

- Questions about printing to [print-preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/print-preview)
- Questions about accessing the Android camera to [android-camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-camera)
- Etc..

What do you think ?

Comment: Preview is also the name of the default [PDF and image viewer on OSX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preview_%28Mac_OS%29) but I don't thing it is used enough to get its own tag.